# Unable to switch views programmatically using a storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, storyboard, segue

I am developing a storyboard-based application, using XCode 4.2. I'm new to storyboards, before that I used to switch views by creating a new instance of a class like this:

```
if (x==1)
{    
    theClass *theView ;
    theView= [[theClass alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [theView setText:theText];
    [reader presentModalViewController:theClass animated:YES]; //where reader is an instance of the ZBar library
}
```

With storyboards, here is the code I am trying:

```
if (x==1)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"theNewView" sender: self];
}
```

then:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"theNewView"])
    {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setText:theText];
        [reader presentModalViewController:[segue destinationViewController] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I made sure that the links are well made and that the `prepareforsegue` method is called, but even with this code, the new view is not being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `presentModalViewController` in your `prepareForSeque` method - this method is for passing information to the new view controller.

See [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310627/transition-between-2-storyboards).

Useful learning [weblog post](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219), for getting started with a storyboard.